# Unable to replace my string with string containing [ and ]

Tags: javascript, replaceall

I am unable to **{info.inner.interest[0]}** string from my total string even though my total string contain string to be replaced

I searched same question in google and tried others code even though that didn't work for me. Please have a look at image below

[image: Error Image]

```js
var a = "text :Array Item : {info.inner.interest[0]}",
  replaceThis = "info.inner.interest[0]",
  outPut = a.replace(new RegExp('{' + replaceThis + '}', 'g'), 'hello me!!')
console.log(outPut);
```

This code is working when I remove **[0]** from **replaceThis** . Why this code is not working when I use **[..]** symbol. Please help me.

Comment: You need to escape the characters `[` and `]` using backslash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many characters have a special meaning in a regular expression. `[` and `]` indicate a *character set*, and `.` indicates *any character*, not a literal dot. If you want to match a string containing any special characters, you need to escape those characters with backslashes first, for example:

```js
const escape = str => str.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

var a = "text :Array Item : {info.inner.interest[0]}",
  replaceThis = "info.inner.interest[0]",
  outPut = a.replace(new RegExp('{' + escape(replaceThis) + '}', 'g'), 'hello me!!')
console.log(outPut);
```

This results in the regular expression being

```
{info\.inner\.interest\[0\]}
```

rather than

```
{info.inner.interest[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```js
var a = "text :Array Item : {info.inner.interest[0]}";
replaceThis = "info.inner.interest[0]";
outPut = a.replace(replaceThis, 'hello me!!');
console.log(outPut);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong regex. It should be `(info\\.inner\\.interest\\[0\\])`. See below code :

```js
var a = "text :Array Item : {info.inner.interest[0]}",
  replaceThis = "info.inner.interest[0]",
  outPut = a.replace(new RegExp('(info\\.inner\\.interest\\[0\\])', 'g'), 'hello me!!')
console.log(outPut);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters in regex. `replaceThis = "info.inner.interest\[0\]"`

Or in shorthand below

```js
var a = "text :Array Item : {info.inner.interest[0]}",
  replaceThis = "info.inner.interest[0]",
  outPut = a.replace(/\[|\]/g, 'hello me!!');
console.log(outPut);
```